# Points of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm beginning to learn some scheme theory and just have a clarifying question regarding the relationship between the ring of regular functions and the points of the scheme. The canonical example of a fat point is the vanishing locus of $x^2$. The structure sheaf captures the difference between $x$ and $x^2$ vanishing because $k[x]/(x)\simeq k\not\simeq k[x]/(x^2)$. $k[x]/(x^2)$ encodes tangent information; its elements are lines. My question is, when we say that the scheme is locally the spectrum of a ring, are we always taking the spectrum of the ring associated to the relevant open set by the structure sheaf?

I'm trying to see if my intuition for affine varieties carries over. For instance, $\text{Spec}\:k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\cong \mathbb{A}^n_k$ and the points of a variety cut out by some functions is given by $\text{Spec}\: k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ for a relevant ideal $I$. So is the space cut out by $x^2$ ($X=\{0\}$) equivalent to $\text{Spec}\:k[x]/(x^2)$?